# Pass $rootScope parameter to named function in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an application that is very moduralized. In this app, I've got a factory whose work is to send notifications to a controller from another module. To achieve this, I'm using the `$rootScope` object to trigger an event called `newNotification` and pass the data.

Everything works fine using the code below:

**notifications.factory.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function notificationsFactory($rootScope) {
        return {
            sendNotification: function(data) {
                switch(data.type) {
                    case 'actors':
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('newNotification', data);
                        break;
                    .....
                }
            } 
        }
    };

    angular.module('features.notifications.factory', [])
    .factory('notificationsFactory', ['$rootScope', notificationsFactory]);
})();
```

So, what's the problem ? Well, the thing is, to get a more clean factory, since more functions will be added, the purpose is to return an object with named function.

To be a bit more clear, what I'm aiming at is something that will look like this:

**notifications.factory.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function notificationsFactory($rootScope) {
        return {
            sendNotification: sendNotification
        }
    };

    function sendNotification(data) {
        switch(data.type) {
            case 'actors':
                $rootScope.$broadcast('newNotification', data);
                break;
            ....
        }
    };

    angular.module('features.notifications.factory', [])
    .factory('notificationsFactory', ['$rootScope', notificationsFactory]);
})();
```

In this case, the problem is that the `$rootScope` object is not defined in the `sendNotification` function, which is obvious. But I can't figure out how to solve this.

I've looked for solution on internet, thing is, the problem is really hard to be expressed clearly without putting some code, thus my post.

Thanks for your consideration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a service instead of a factory, you can transfer the injected dependencies using `this`. Using a service in this way is even nicer, when you use ES6 classes, and makes you **slightly** more Angular 2.0 ready.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function NotificationsService($rootScope) {
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    };

    NotificationsService.prototype.sendNotification = function sendNotification(data) {
        switch(data.type) {
            case 'actors':
                this.$rootScope.$broadcast('newNotification', data);
                break;
            ....
        }
    };

    angular.module('features.notifications.service', [])
    .service('NotificationsService', ['$rootScope', NotificationsService]);
})();
```

ES6 Version:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    class NotificationsService {
        constructor($rootScope) {
            this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        }

        sendNotification(data) {
            switch(data.type) {
                case 'actors':
                    this.$rootScope.$broadcast('newNotification', data);
                    break;
                ....
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('features.notifications.service', [])
    .service('NotificationsService', ['$rootScope', NotificationsService]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `sendNotification`-function inside your `notificationsFactory`- factory function:

```
function notificationsFactory($rootScope) {
    function sendNotification(data) {
        switch(data.type) {
            case 'actors':
                $rootScope.$broadcast('newNotification', data);
                break;
            ....
        }
      };
      return {
          sendNotification: sendNotification
      }
    };
```

or use service instead of factory and you can write something like this:

```
function notificationsFactory($rootScope) {
    this.sendNotification = function(data) {
        switch(data.type) {
            case 'actors':
                $rootScope.$broadcast('newNotification', data);
                break;
            ....
        }
      };
    };
```

Comment: Many thanks, your solution works fine :) however, I validated the response of @Ori Drori that looks more cleaner